# How to compare two tables in SQL if 2 columns have the same data - Codeigniter?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, datatable

How can I compare two columns in two different tables if it has the same data using the SQL query? I'm working on the Codeigniter framework.
Table one called: ci_admin and the column name is: admin_id.
table two called: active_ingredient and the column name is user_id.

and I'm using the datatable_json function to view all data in tables.

when I'm using the code below, it shows all data in the database, and I need to show the data where admin_id = user_id

this code in model:

```
        $wh =array();
        $SQL ='SELECT * FROM active_ingredient';
        $wh[] = "SELECT 1
        FROM   ci_admin
        WHERE  ci_admin.admin_id = active_ingredient.user_id";

        if(count($wh)>0)
        {               $WHERE = implode(' and ',$wh);
            return $this->datatable->LoadJson($SQL,$WHERE);
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->datatable->LoadJson($SQL);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use JOINS for getting data from multiple tables with comparison columns**

```
$SQL = 'SELECT active_ingredient.*,ci_admin.* FROM active_ingredient 
LEFT JOIN ci_admin on (active_ingredient.user_id = ci_admin.admin_id)';
```

Then return your above SQL query

```
return $this->datatable->LoadJson($SQL);
```